# SQL Insert trigger access old values cleanly?

Tags: sql

I'm new to SQL beyond basic queries / inserts (as you'll see quickly as you read further)

Here's a (very) simplified example.

I have table 'person' like:

```
 UID | NAME | AGE | LOCATION
 45  | bob  | 23  | Canada 
 31  | bill | 20  | Romania
```

and a second table 'person_history' like:

```
UID | PID | NAME | AGE | LOCATION
 -  |  -  |  -   |  -  |     -
```

when I insert into this table like

```
update person set age=10 where UID==45
```

I want my trigger to fire, to access the existing values in person, and to push them into the second table, and then continue with the original insert.

The way I can think to do this is:

```
 Select uid, name, age, location, 
 into v_uid, v_name, v_age, v_location 
 from person 
 where uid = :new.uid
```

then do the insert like

```
 Insert into person_history(UID, PID, NAME, AGE, LOCATION) 
 VALUES (sequence.nextval, v_uid, v_name, v_age, v_location);
```

but this seems like a very round-about way of doing it - especially if the table has 50 columns.

Is this the correct method, and is there a more elegant way of approaching this problem.

Again, keep in mind how new I am to all of this, so examples would be really helpful.

Comment: What DBMS do you use? In general i think your approach is perfectly  good. If you worry about enumerating the columns i would reconsider if it is really necessary to have all columns in the history.

Answer (score 0):

why do you do this part?:

```
 Select uid, name, age, location, 
 into v_uid, v_name, v_age, v_location 
 from person 
 where uid = :new.uid
```

Just use this approach:

```
 INSERT INTO person_history(UID, PID, NAME, AGE, LOCATION) 
 VALUES (sequence.nextval, ::new.uid, ::new.name, ::new.age, ::new.location);
```

Regarding the quantity of columns, I'm not sure it is possible to do it in a "smarter" way.